# How to put the response of .then() function in module.exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, request, module.exports

```
function getData() {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    method: "GET",
    },
   function (err, res, body) {
    if(!err)
    resolve(res);
    else
    reject(err);
});
})  
}
   getData().then((val) => {
        module.exports = val;
   });
```

Here, I am using a REST API to get some data with request npm module. Since request doesn't return promise so I wrapped it up in a promise and resolved for the response.
 Later, I put a .then() to the function returning promise and inside .then() I put the module.exports = val.
However, I don't want to put the module.exports inside .then().

Is there any other way to get the data asycnchronously to module.exports.

Comment: You don't. Export the promise instead.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi that's what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the promise should be returned. The `.then` or `await` should be implemented by the code that imports and calls this module/function.

Comment: Hey, I have a doubt regarding the asynchronous nature. Is there any change that the globalVal goes as undefined in module.exports that is before the .then() code runs.
Also, for solution I think the one you mentioned above i.e. returning the promise in the module.exports should be a very nice solution

Comment: I made a mistake in my answer here, globalVal will be returned as undefined in module.exports. The value of globalVal will be updated once the `.then` code runs. Thanks for pointing that out. Will update my answer. In the code example I had given previously, `module.exports = globalVal` will be executed before `.then()` code runs.

Comment: Yes, exporting the promise one is perfectly fine. I did the same as the solution to the problem.